# Convert postresql jsonb query in to Spring JPA query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to convert the below query into Spring JPA nativequery but I couldnt find a way to pass parameters.

```
SELECT * FROM references 
WHERE json_data -> 'References' @> 
any(cast(ARRAY['[{"Id": "001", "Type": "Type-1"}]', '[{"Id": "004", "Type": "Type-4"}]'] as jsonb[]))
```

Below is the json data in the jsonb column.

```
{
    "CorrelationId": "1234-123-123",
    "References": [
        {
            "Id": "001",
            "Type": "Type-1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "002",
            "Type": "Type-2"
        },
        {
            "Id": "003",
            "Type": "Type-3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Spring JPA query: This is not working

```
  @Query(
        value = """
        SELECT * FROM references 
        WHERE json_data -> 'References' @> 
        any(cast(ARRAY[:ids] as jsonb[]))
        """,
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun findAllByReferences(@Param("ids") ids: List<String>)
```

Calling Function:

```
repository.findAllByReferences("[{\"Id\": \"001\", \"Type\": \"Type-1\"}]", "[{\"Id\": \"004\", \"Type\": \"Type-4\"}]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once that there is a JSON-based workflow my suggestion is to serialize the the arguments' list into a valid JSON array of objects

`[{"Id": "001", "Type": "Type-1"}, {"Id": "004", "Type": "Type-4"}]`

and use a bit modified query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM refs 
WHERE json_data -> 'References' @> any(
 array(select jsonb_build_array(j) from jsonb_array_elements(cast(:ids as jsonb)) j)
);
```

Please note that `references` is a reserved word. Give your table a different name (I used `refs` above) or double-quote the name.

**Edit**

or the less natural, still valid JSON

`[[{"Id": "001", "Type": "Type-1"}], [{"Id": "004", "Type": "Type-4"}]]`

and somewhat simpler

```sql
SELECT * FROM refs 
WHERE json_data -> 'References' @> any(
 array(select jsonb_array_elements(cast(:ids as jsonb)))
);
```

Using PostgreSQL postfix cast syntax, `cast(:ids as jsonb)` becomes `:ids\\:\\:jsonb`. Indeed JPA is not very smart on colons.

Comment: Thank you, this works well and I agree with first option.